# Measuring given velocity, force

Tags: kinematics

This is a basic doubt I always had in mind but never dared to ask anyone back then but I feel like I should let it out now.

When we say we throw a projectile velocity with $30$ m$\cdot$s$^{-1}$ velocity, how do we measure that velocity? I mean a normal person wouldn't have any way to figure that out. If we use a machine of some kind, how does the machine give the reading that we are throwing with that velocity? Because we need two points in to calculate velocity but there is no way to figure out what the initial velocity is without any information. The same applies for forces. When we say we are applying $30$ N force, how do we know that we are applying a force of that exact magnitude? What is the way to measure that force?

I beg pardon if these questions are silly and absurd but I really want to know the answers from the respected physics lovers.

Comment: In Major League Baseball they use a radar gun

Comment: That's exactly my question,how does the machine measure that?What are the metrics?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not you but the police  can measure velocity  of that magnitude by radar, and they  do it all the time.
With the projectile if you know the height and it starts horizontally  you can measure where it reaches ground. You also could use two Photoelectric barriers.
Forces can bei measured with springs, or weights.

Comment: But how does that radar measure it?

Comment: you can find it out in many sources in the internet. maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_radar